# Convention for sharing data between web app and native apps

Tags: rest, design-patterns, architecture

When you have a native app and a web app that both use the same data, what is the best/conventional way of retrieving that data? This question was partly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+share+data+between+web+app+and+mobile+app), but it suggests creating a REST API. Why not just access the database directly from both apps?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. I remember when I started programming I was using firebase and I had a similar doubt, since Firebase does it all for you. Therefore an API doesnt feel necessary.

However, an API is, in its way, a direct access to your database. You call an endpoint and it returns the data from the database. It could even process the data before returning, making your life easier.

Also, by building an API you won't need to build the same logic twice to handle your database connections in mobile and web. You'll only call the endpoint and get whatever data you need.

Comment: A rest API allows you to return data in a complex but consistent structure, rather than having to deal with SQL joins, reformatting data, fetching related entities, etc. separately in each app.